# Set up while statement to print out methods?

Tags: java, methods

Not the best title but basically I want to ask the user to enter a temperature, and then displays a list of substances that will freeze at that temperature and those that boil at that temperature. I want it to be in a while loop and I want the user to be able to go until they want to stop. Heres what I have so far, my first class and then a tester

```
public class FreezingPoint {

    private int temperature;

    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature() {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public boolean isEthylFreezing() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature <= -173.0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }

    public boolean isEthylBoiling() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature >= 172.0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }

    public boolean isOxygenFreezing() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature <= -362.0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }

    public boolean isOxygenBoiling() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature >= -306.0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }

    public boolean isWaterFreezing() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature <= 32)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }

    public boolean isWaterBoiling() {
        boolean status;

        if (temperature >= 212)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;

        return status;
    }
}
```

and now tester class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestFreezingPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FreezingPoint fp = new FreezingPoint();
        double temperature;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter a temp");
        temperature = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Is Water Freezing?" + fp.isWaterFreezing());
    }
}
```

My problem is that the code isn't working properly and I'm confused as to where to go from here. I know how to setup the while loop and how to make it go until I want to stop but I'm not sure on how to properly print out the list of substances that will be displayed based off the users inputted temperature

Any help appreciated, pretty new to java and been stuck on this awhile

Thanks

Comment: Not working properly? What's going wrong, what's your error?

Comment: you have a lot of USELESS in your methods, reduce like this : `public boolean isEthylBoiling(){ return  temperature >= 172.0; }` for each one

Comment: My eyes might be weak but in your `main` method, you read the temperature but you do not assign it to your `FreezingPoint`. Also, as azro answer suggests, I think you'll gain a lot by redesigning a bit your classes and considering `Substance` as an object with critical temperature as attributes

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer which helped you the most by checking the green mark. Otherwise, please comment to the answer to get complementary information

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a different way of testing if something boils or freezes at a given temperature. In your example you would have to add two methods for every substance and then find a way to cycle through them.

It would probably be a lot easier if you used for example a list and then use a switch() statement to only add the substances to the list that boil or freeze at the given temperature. If you make a method that does so and give it the temperature as a parameter and have it return the populated list, you could easily loop through the list and print out every element.

I made a quick example for you:

```
public List<String> getSubstances(int temperature){

    List<String> substances = new ArrayList<String>();

    switch(temperature){

        case 0:
            substances.add("Water");

        case 100:
            substances.add("Water");


    }

    return substances;

}
```

This would be a way easier solution and you can cycle through the list very easily to print it out.

Comment: If you look at OP's checks, you'll see that he is not using equality but comparison. Consequently, he is not looking for the critical temperature but given a temperature, what is the state of water, oxygen, etc. So a `switch` won't do. For instance, if input is `150` (Celsius degrees), what is your output?

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry, didn't realize that. Anyways, creating an if statement like `if(0<temperature & temperature<101){substances.add("Water");}` is better than creating a new method for every substance as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a class to represent the substances:

```
public class Substance {

    private String name;
    private double tempFreeze;
    private double tempBoil;

    public Substance(String name, double tempFreeze, double tempBoil) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tempFreeze = tempFreeze;
        this.tempBoil = tempBoil;
    }

    public double getTempBoil() {     return tempBoil;  }
    public double getTempFreeze() {    return tempFreeze;  }
    public String getName() {     return name;  }

    public String getState(double temp) {
        if (temp <= tempFreeze) {
            return "freeze";
        } else if (temp >= tempBoil) {
            return "boil";
        }
        return "liquid";
   }
}
```

---

To be used like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Substance> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Substance("ethyl", -173, 172));
    list.add(new Substance("Oxygen", -362, -306));
    list.add(new Substance("water", 32, 212));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("please enter a temp");
        double temperature = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();                   //consume return char

        for (Substance s : list) {
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " is in state : " + s.getState(temperature));
        }

        System.out.println("\nDo you want to stop ? Write 'yes' to stop");
    } while (!sc.nextLine().contains("y"));
}
```

---

Execution example :

```
please enter a temp
125
ethyl is in state : liquid
Oxygen is in state : boil
water is in state : liquid

Do you want to stop ? Write 'yes' to stop
y
```

Comment: If I want to be picky/annoying, may I know why you did choose this design for your `getState(double)` method over a basic `if ... else if .... else` ?</annoying>. Upvote for class suggestion :)

Comment: @Al1 because i "like" ternary^^ but i changed, easier this way to understand